# animation in android activities not working

Tags: android, translation, android-animation

I have made 4 activities in android they all are same. They just have a relative layout and that layout has 4 different images as backgroud,i have set animation on that for 2000miliseconds for example 1st screen should come from right.second from left...etc..I have implemented as below but its not working pls help me..!
**screen1.java**

```
Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        startAnimatedActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity1.this,
                    SplashActivity2.class),
                    CustAnimatedActivity.SLIDE_FROM_RIGHT);
        finish();
    }
};
splashThread.start();
```

same code for 3 activity also..!

Comment: show logcat if any error comes...

Comment: @jigar actually what's you try can u tell me please ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati-Dear waht i need is i have 4 different screens,!st screen should strat from let,then second from right,third from top and forth from bottom in sense of animation (sliding)

Comment: @SilentKiller-No error man....!my animation is not working...!

Comment: You are starting the activity from a non-ui thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used "handler" in place of "thread" .I have tried following code..and its working like butter..!

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
        {
            try
            {
                Intent intent = null;
                intent = new Intent(SplashActivity1.this,
                        SplashActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animated_activity_slide_left_in, R.anim.animated_activity_slide_right_out);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };
```